# Good Text for Shapiro-Wilk Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, references, inference, goodness-of-fit

I was wondering if anyone can give me some good texts for understanding the Shapiro-Wilk test.

I'm searching for an intermediate level text, not too simple like the wikipedia page (it gives very little information) and not too complicated like the original paper from the two authors.

Any suggestion is appreciated! 
Thank you guys !!

Comment: Which Wikipedia page are you referring to?  The [one in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test?wprov=sfla1)?

Comment: Yes yes, the one in english

Comment: What's missing from the article that you are looking for?

Comment: What did you want to know about it? It's a bit hard to guess what kind of information you seek.

Comment: For example how we reached the test statistic W (where it came from and what it represent), why this test is considered one of the best (it s only wirtten that with montecarlo simulations it has been  proved it). I know my question may sound silly but i have to do a detailed explanation of this test and only the material on the wikipedia page is not enough. If you have any book, or paper to suggest it would be fantastic man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find the discussion of the test in D'Agostino & Stephens' *Goodness of Fit Techniques* of some use.

It is a ratio of two different estimates of variance under normality, the denominator the usual variance estimate and the numerator one based on the square of a linear function of the order statistics.

Apart from a scaling factor in the numerator and denominator, you can see that [at the Wikipedia page for the test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test#Theory)

It's also closely related to a linear function of the squared correlation between the order statistics (the values sorted into order) and the expected normal order statistics (i.e. it's closely related to the Shapiro-Francia and Ryan-Joiner tests) -- e.g. see the first page here https://www1.fpl.fs.fed.us/spl1991.pdf, the paragraph starting "Filliben", but uses information in the covariance of the order statistics to get a (usually) somewhat more powerful test for small samples.

There's also a large number of questions on site about the Shapiro-Wilk test (I've answered more than 50, so there'll be considerably more than that) at least some of which address the things you are after, so I'd also recommend trying a site-search.